In Typescript, can one define that a parameter has to be a field of a object that might be undefined?
I have an interface that has an optional field with another interface. Can I create a function that expects a field of that second interface?
interface A {
  b?: B;
  c: B;
}

interface B {
  y?: string;
}

function outputfield<T extends object, K extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K]>
  (model: T, field1: K, field2: K2): void {
  console.log(model, field1, field2);
}

const a: A = { c: {} }

outputfield(a, 'b', 'y');
// works

outputfield(a, 'c', 'y');
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

How do I have to change the annotation of outputfield?

This should work I believe:
function outputfield<
  T extends object,
  K extends keyof T,
  K2 extends keyof NonNullable<T[K]>
>(model: T, field1: K, field2: K2): void {
  console.log(model, field1, field2);
}


Yes! That works. NonNullable solves it. Thanks

You can use the type utilities Partial and Record (documented below) to constrain the generic type parameter of the root object like this:
TS Playground
interface A {
  b?: B;
  c: B;
}

interface B {
  y?: string;
}

function outputfield<
  K2 extends PropertyKey,
  K1 extends PropertyKey,
  T extends Partial<Record<K1, Partial<Record<K2, unknown>>>>,
>(model: T, field1: K1, field2: K2): void {
  console.log(model, field1, field2);
}

declare const a: A;
outputfield(a, "b", "y"); // ok
outputfield(a, "c", "y"); // ok


Type utility information from the handbook:
Partial<Type>

Constructs a type with all properties of Type set to optional. This utility will return a type that represents all subsets of a given type.

Record<Keys, Type>

Constructs an object type whose property keys are Keys and whose property values are Type. This utility can be used to map the properties of a type to another type.


seems too complex comparing to the other answer, what benefits?

^ @AlexanderNenashev It's about Design thinking: see Bottom-up and top-down design — the difference is in the way that the constraint is derived: one defines it as "start with any object, and then pick valid keys from the object" — the other as "define valid keys and an object that meets those predefined expectations"

yes, it's clear, but in this particular case the benefits are not obvious, also the performance of TS is interesting
